# How to fix "Add a reference to "MonoAndroid,Version=v12.0"" (actually trying to target 13) on XamarinAndroid build task for AzureDevops?

Tags: azure-devops, xamarin.android, msbuild, mono

I'm getting this error from a build script for Xamarin.Android that previously has worked for older versions of Android:

```
##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\16.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets(198,5): Error : Your project does not reference "MonoAndroid,Version=v12.0" framework. Add a reference to "MonoAndroid,Version=v12.0" in the "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet restore.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\16.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets;linenumber=198;columnnumber=5;code=;]Your project does not reference "MonoAndroid,Version=v12.0" framework. Add a reference to "MonoAndroid,Version=v12.0" in the "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet restore.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\16.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets(198,5): error : Your project does not reference "MonoAndroid,Version=v12.0" framework. Add a reference to "MonoAndroid,Version=v12.0" in the "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet restore. [D:\a\1\s\MyProject.Xamarin\MyProject.Android\MyProject.Android.csproj]
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logdetail id=e408d669-be6f-49f1-b429-2e88049c5407;parentid=b84e3e4f-4467-4eae-9902-6f94de004f74;type=Build;result=Failed;finishtime=2022-08-31T13:01:13.7014902Z;progress=100;state=Completed;parentid=b84e3e4f-4467-4eae-9902-6f94de004f74;name=;]
Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\MyProject.Xamarin\MyProject.Android\MyProject.Android.csproj" (PackageForAndroid target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```

Initially, this error made sense to me. For a specific test configuration I was trying to build for, I didn't have a TargetFrameWork set in the Android project. I did when testing for debug on my machine and it built, so I set this to v13 (as this is the version I intend to distribute).

Still the same error, so I set it to v12. And still the same error.

I've also tried manually setting the JDK to 11 (the most recent, right?) and changing the version of Visual Studio to the latest (still 2019 according to the logs?).

I've also set MS Build to be the latest, and set UseLatestPlatformSdk to be true. But still receiving this error.

Here is the part of my script that is failing:

```
task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**/*.sln'
    msbuildArgs: '/t:Restore'
    vsVersion: 'latest'

 task: XamarinAndroid@1
  inputs:
    projectFile: '**/*droid.csproj'
    outputDirectory: '$(outputDirectory)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildVersionOption: 'latest'
    msbuildArguments: '/p:increaseBuildNumber=1'
    jdkOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
```

Documentation for building Xamarin.Android 13 on Azure Devops is slim. Does anybody see what I might be doing wrong? Can I manually set the Mono.Android version for this agent somewhere perhaps?

Comment: #meToo
ever find a solution. This one keeps popping up on me

Comment: Not yet, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by adding reference via nuget to:

`Xamarin.AndroidX.Core`

Comment: Pointed me in the right direction. I just needed to update the `Xamarin.AndroidX. Arch.Core.Runtime' nuget.